# NextJS throwing error whenever changing timezone using react-timezone-select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a NextJS project which im trying to allow users to enter their timezone based on `react-timezone-select`. when it first loads, it grabs the users timezone from the api and sets it in the select, but every time i go to change the timezone i get the following error

```
ReferenceError: onChange is not defined
```

I've copied it exactly from the `react-timezone-select` docs but cant seem to figure out whats going on.

```
import { useTimezoneSelect, allTimezones } from 'react-timezone-select'

const labelStyle = 'original'
const timezones = {
    ...allTimezones
}

const Settings = () => {
    const [timezone, setTimezone] = useState('')

    const { options, parseTimezone } = useTimezoneSelect({ labelStyle, timezones })

    const { data: usertimezone, error } = useSWR('/api/user/timezone', () => 
        axios.get('/api/user/timezone')
            .then(response => response.data.data)
    )

    useEffect(() => {
        if (usertimezone?.timezone) {
            setTimezone(usertimezone.timezone)
        }
    }, [usertimezone?.timezone])

    return (
        <select
            id="timezone"
            name="timezone"
            value={timezone}
            onChange={e => onChange(parseTimezone(e.currentTarget.value))}
        >
            {options.map(option => (
                <option key={option.value} value={option.value}>{option.label}</option>
            ))}
        </select>
    )
}
```

Comment: You're invoking an `onChange` callback function, but it's not defined above the return statement. You'll either have to define it and have it update your `timezone` state value using `setTimezone` state setter, or you can simply swap `e => onChange(...)` for the `setTimezone` state setter: 
```onChange={e => setTimezone(parseTimezone(e.currentTarget.value))}```